# VideoCapture opencv + rstp + Qt c++ fails

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am trying to capture some video from my IP-camera, but only got theese artefacts:

[image: artefacts]

How do I fix it? Help me, please! Here is my code:

```
QString str1 = "rtsp://admin:000000@192.168.1.100:554/H264?ch=1&subtype=0";

cv::VideoCapture vcap = VideoCapture(str1.toStdString());
   cv::Mat image;

   if(!vcap.isOpened())
      {
          qDebug() << "Input error\n";
          return;
      }
namedWindow("window",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
for(;;) {

    Mat frame;
    if(vcap.grab())
       vcap.retrieve(image);

    if (image.empty())
       break;
           
    imshow("window", image);

    waitKey(1);
}
```